# PHP: Tank Auth, require a certain email address to login

Tags: php, codeigniter, tankauth

So I have just setup tank auth, I have not changed anything yet so everything should be default. It works perfectly fine. However I want to require for a certain domain for emails to be able to login. For now I will say gmail. So how can i make it so it checks that the email address has @gmail.com in it before the user can register. I have found where the valid email error message is and can change that but i cannot find where the actual check for the valid email.

Comment: https://github.com/ilkon/Tank-Auth/blob/master/application/controllers/auth.php Line 132 (valid_email)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tank auth is using CI's default `valid_email` validation rule, found in the Form Validation class.

It's definitely a strange thing to want to do, but you can create a [callback validation function](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#callbacks) and add it to your form validation rules on the registration page.

This is basically the equivalent of an `ends_with` rule, but adds the "@":

```
// Check if the inputs last characters matches the parameter
function is_email_domain($input, $domain) {
   $domain_str = '@'.$domain;
   $result = strpos($input, $domain_str) === (strlen($input) - strlen($domain_str));
   if ( ! $result) $this->form_validation->set_message('is_email_domain', 'The %s field must be a %s email address');
   return $result;
}
```

So create the callback function in your controller and add it to the validation:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules(
    'email',
    'Email',
    'trim|required|xss_clean|valid_email|callback_is_email_domain[gmail.com]'
);
```

Comment: HAHA! This worked great thanks! Also a good learning experience. Thank you for the in-depth response. As far as the strangeness of the request, it is for a website that is for my school (ish) and we want the user to have a valid school email in order to register so we can make sure they are a student. Of course it is not going to be gmail but same thing. Again, thank you!